# ReferenceError: document is not defined (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

(React Native / Expo environment)

I am trying to port a project to Expo (seems to be working fine in a plain React Native environment).

I have bumped into a problem where there's an exception coming from the url-polyfill library ('document is not defined'), as it's trying to access the document global variable which is indeed undefined.

Tried to google this but not much came up.

So my question is basically:

How to polyfill URL in a RN (Expo) environment (need to polyfill otherwise I get a 'creating URL objects is not supported yet' exception)?

Also, not quite sure if the global document variable is supposed to be available in React Native, and maybe only unavailable in Expo?

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this one off, I managed to solve the problem by using a different URL implementation, whatwg-url.

The problem with url-polyfill, that it assumes a browser environment, with the usual globals being available.